# Jenkins svn connection refused

Tags: svn, proxy, jenkins

Tried to configured Jenkins to connect to a remote svn for build job but failed. The error is `"svn: OPTIONS /svnpath failed"`, due to `connection refused`.

I'm behind proxy. Here is the configuration and observation:

- `~/.subversion/servers` has proxy configured
- `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins` has proxy configured `JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dhttp.proxyHost=[ip] -DhttpProxyPort=[port] -Dhttp.auth.preference=Basic"`
- in console, can do `svn checkout https://company.com/svnpath` without problem
- tried use svnkit and run `svn checkout https://company.com/svnpath`, no problem either

I'm getting confused. Is it proxy problem? Or some other settings in Jenkins I need to set?

Update:

Got it working, I typed the port parameter wrong: `JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dhttp.proxyHost=[ip] -Dhttp.proxyPort=[port] -Dhttp.auth.preference=Basic"`

Comment: If it literally says "svn: OPTIONS /svnpath failed" could it jusr be that you are missing a replacement char like $OPTIONS for it to be replaced correctly by the actual command in the config?

Comment: As you seem to have fixed the problem, please answer your own question and mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The Proxy-Port parameter (capital "P") was typed wrong:

> JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dhttp.proxyHost=[ip]
>   -Dhttp.proxyPort=[port] -Dhttp.auth.preference=Basic"

Since the author does not add the solution as an answer, I thought I do as Martin Foot suggested in his comment...

Answer (score 0):

I fought the same symptoms as @jackysee (who faced them on *nix) on a Windows 7 box running Jenkins 1.444.  Like @jackysee, I thought I had server-side proxy configuration issues, but my problem turned out to be purely a client-side Subversion proxy setup issue. For the `SYSTEM` user, I fixed the following file:

```
Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\servers
```

For a normal Windows user (easier for testing purposes), fix the following file instead:

```
Users\[uname]\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\servers
```

Under the `[groups]` section, I had incorrectly specified the external Subversion repository.  The error this gave (similar to @jackysee's) was `svn: OPTIONS /svn failed`.  Here was the **incorrect** configuration:

```
[groups]  
wwj = worldwind31.arc.nasa.gov/svn
```

And here's the fix that worked for me:

```
[groups]
wwj = worldwind31.arc.nasa.gov
```

I later found that the [Subversion book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) gives a *much* better description of the purpose of the `[groups]` section than the misleading comments in the `servers` file.  The Subversion book explains that the values in the `[groups]` section are used to identify **hostnames** while the comments in the `servers` file mislead you to believe that the values should be repository URLs (incorrect).